# Wait for pointer-events in Cypress by default

Tags: cypress, pointer-events

The [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) CSS property sets under what circumstances (if any) a particular graphic element can become the target of pointer events.
I use this property to prevent interaction with some sections of a web application for a short time while content is updating.

This causes problems with end to end tests run through Cypress. Cypress is correctly blocked from interacting with an element with pointer-events set to none. However, instead of failing immediately, I would like Cypress to wait for the element to become intractable. This is the [default behaviour](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/interacting-with-elements.html#Actionability) for elements which are `disabled`, `readonly`, animating etc.

My question is: Is there any way to make Cypress apply this default behaviour to elements with `pointer-events` set to `none` (or with a parent whose `pointer-events` is set to `none`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to have been added with Cypress `5.6.0`!

Here's the update in Cypress' issues:

https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/9227#issuecomment-729465861